# How to hide a table rows that had the value 0?

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have the next table code, and I have a lot of `values = 0`, so I need to hide or display none the rows that have the value = 0.

I tried different methods in javaScript but those didn't work and the reason why the value = 0 is beacause I used a function like this:

```
if ($status['id'] == 70) {
    $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;
}
```

Can I use this function to display none or hide the rows? Beacause I need these rows to not be displayed not to appear 0! But it's ok even if they appear 0 but I need them to not be displayed!

```css
th.sorting_asc {
  display: none;
}

td.sorting_1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-projects dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="DataTables_Table_0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorting_asc" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0" style="">#</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Task Status</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Task Name</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Items</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Estimated Time (min.)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Real Time (min.)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Estimated Cost (Lei)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Real Cost (Lei)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0"><span class="mrp">Manual Real Price (Lei Fara TVA)&nbsp;</span> <span class="prc">Price</span></th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">
        <div class="priority1">Priority</div><span class="ceva">Price</span> <span class="priceminus">Price - Real Cost</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1886">1886</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1887">1887</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1889">1889</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1890">1890</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1927">1927</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1928">1928</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1959">1959</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1960">1960</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1969">1969</a></td>
      <td><span class="inline-block label" style="color:#84c529;border:1px solid #84c529;">Expediat Tapet <img src="http://crm.amco.ro/wallpaper.png" alt="Girl in a jacket">
                    <div class="dropdown inline-block mleft5 table-export-exclude"><a class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="tableTaskStatus-1969" style="font-size:14px;vertical-align:middle;"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change Status"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><br></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td><a class="display-block main-tasks-table-href-name" href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1969">test 4.02.21</a></td>
      <td>
        <div>1.Manopera <strong>(1)</strong></div>
      </td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">60</span> | (1 0)</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>83</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>101.26</td>
      <td>94.52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lastrowbold" id="anchor">
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td>Total By Real Time: 4.00 Min</td>
      <td>Total By Estimated Cost: 83.00 Lei</td>
      <td>Total By Real Cost: 7.00 Lei</td>
      <td id="alltaskspricetotal">Total By Price: 101.26 Lei</td>
      <td>Price - Total Cost: 94.52 Lei</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

PHP file one

````php
```$realTime = get_calc_task_real_logged_time($aRow['id']);
  $assignees_ids = $aRow['assignees_ids'];
  $assignees_id = explode(',', $assignees_ids);
  $calA = get_task_user_hourly_rate($assignees_id[0]); // hourly_rate
  $calB = get_task_custom_billable_amount($aRow['id']);
  // facut de mine
  // if($aRow['task_item_percentage']){  
  //   $calC = ((round($itemtotal + ((($calA * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60))))*($aRow['task_item_percentage']/100)))+(round($itemtotal + (($calA * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60))));
  //  // $calC = ($itemtotal*$aRow['task_item_percentage']/100)+$itemtotal; // additionalPriceTotal
  // }
  //   else{
  //  $calC = ($itemtotal+$aRow['task_item_manual_total_price']-$itemtotal);
  // }
  if($aRow['task_item_percentage']){
    //$calC = ($itemtotal*$aRow['task_item_percentage']/100)+$itemtotal; // additionalPriceTotal
$calC = ((round($itemtotal + ((($calA * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60))))*($aRow['task_item_percentage']/100)))+(round($itemtotal + (($calA * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60))));
  }
    else{
    $calC = ($itemtotal+$aRow['task_item_manual_total_price']-$itemtotal);
  }
    $duration = $aRow['task_duration'];    // facut de mine
    $durationNatural = intVal($duration/60);  // facut de mine
    $durationRest = $duration % 60;  // facut de mine
  $estimateCost += round($itemtotal+($calA * $aRow['task_duration'] / 60)); // facut de mine  
  $realCost = $itemtotal+$calB;  // facut de mine
  $calCminusrealcost = $calC - $realCost;   // facut de mine
   $canChangeStatus = ($aRow['current_user_is_creator'] != '0' || $aRow['current_user_is_assigned'] || has_permission('tasks', '', 'edit'));
  $status   = get_task_status_by_id($aRow['status']);
  $outputStatus  = '';
  $outputStatus .= '<span class="inline-block label" style="color:' . $status['color'] . ';border:1px solid ' . $status['color'] . '" task-status-table="' . $aRow['status'] . '">';
  $outputStatus .= $status['name'];
  if ($canChangeStatus) {
  $outputStatus .= '<div class="dropdown inline-block mleft5 table-export-exclude">';
  $outputStatus .= '<a href="#" style="font-size:14px;vertical-align:middle;" class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" id="tableTaskStatus-' . $aRow['id'] . '" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">';
  $outputStatus .= '<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . _l('ticket_single_change_status') . '"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
  $outputStatus .= '</a>';
  $outputStatus .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="tableTaskStatus-' . $aRow['id'] . '">';
  foreach ($task_statuses as $taskChangeStatus) {
    if ($aRow['status'] != $taskChangeStatus['id']) {
    $outputStatus .= '<li>
     <a href="#" onclick="task_mark_as(' . $taskChangeStatus['id'] . ',' . $aRow['id'] . '); return false;">
       ' . _l('task_mark_as', $taskChangeStatus['name']) . '
     </a>
    </li>';
    }
  }  
  // $totalall = $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;  
  if ($status['id'] == 52) {  
    $calC = 0;
  }
  // filtru pentru taskuri tricouri si alte produse (id = 70 si 71)  
  // if ($totalall == 0) {
  //   display: none;
  // }  
  if ($status['id'] == 70) {
   $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;
  }
  if ($status['id'] == 71) {  
   $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;
  }
  if ($status['id'] == 2) {  
   $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;
  }
  if ($status['id'] == 5) {  
   $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;
  }
   if ($status['id'] == 80) {  
   $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;
  }
  if ($status['id'] == 82) {
   $outputStatus = $outputName = $itemName = $duration = $durationNatural = $durationRest = $realTime = $estimateCost = $realCost = $calC = $calCminusrealcost = 0;
  }
  // filtru pentru taskuri tricouri si alte produse
  $outputStatus .= '</ul>';
  $outputStatus .= '</div>';
  }
  $outputStatus .= '</span>';
  $row[] = $outputStatus;
  $row[] = $outputName;
  $row[] = $itemName;
  $row[] = "<span style='font-weight:900'>$duration</span> | ($durationNatural $durationRest)";  // facut de mine
  $row[] = round($realTime/60);
  $row[] = round($estimateCost);
  $row[] = round($realCost);
  $row[] = round($realCost);
  $row[] = $calC;   // facut de mine
  $row[] = $calCminusrealcost;   // facut de mine
  $output['aaData'][] = $row;
  }
}```
````

php file 2

````
$table_data = [
   _l('the_number_sign'),
   _l('Task Status'),
   _l('Task Name'),
   _l('Items'),
   _l('Estimated Time (min.)'),
   _l('Real Time (min.)'),
   _l('Estimated Cost (Lei)'),
   _l('Real Cost (Lei)'),
   _l('Real Cost (Lei)'),     // facut de mine
   
];

$custom_fields = get_custom_fields('projects',
    ['show_on_table' => 1]
);

foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
    array_push($table_data, $field['name']);
}

$table_data = hooks()->apply_filters('projects_table_columns', $table_data);

render_datatable($table_data, 'projects'); ```



    
and file 3 

<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?php init_head(); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content taskreporttable">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel_s">
              <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="row mbot15">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h4 class="no-margin"><?php echo _l('Tasks Reports List'); ?></h4>
        
     <!--// facut de mine webtask-->
     <div class="col-md-11" style="display:none">
                        
                        <?php $this->load->view('admin/tasks/reports_filter_by',array('view_table_name'=>'.table-tasks')); ?>
                     </div>
                     
                     
                  <div>
 <!--// facut de mine webtask-->
                    <a href="<?php echo admin_url('tasks/reports/'); ?>" class="btn btn-default mleft10 pull-left hidden-xs">Raport Total</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo admin_url('tasks/tricourireports/'); ?>" class="btn btn-default mleft10 pull-left hidden-xs">Rapoarte Tricouri</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo admin_url('tasks/tablourireports/'); ?>" class="btn btn-default mleft10 pull-left hidden-xs">Rapoarte Tablouri</a>
                   <a href="<?php echo admin_url('tasks/projectreports/'); ?>" class="btn btn-default mleft10 pull-left hidden-xs">Project Reports</a>
                  </div>

                  <?php
                  $_where = '';
                  if(!has_permission('projects','','view')){
                    $_where = 'id IN (SELECT project_id FROM '.db_prefix().'project_members WHERE staff_id='.get_staff_user_id().')';
                  }
                  ?>
                </div>
                <div class="_filters _hidden_inputs">
                  <?php
                  echo form_hidden('my_projects');
                  foreach($statuses as $status){
                   $value = $status['id'];
                   
                     if($status['filter_default'] == false && !$this->input->get('status')){
                        $value = '';
                     } else if($this->input->get('status')) {
                        $value = ($this->input->get('status') == $status['id'] ? $status['id'] : "");
                     }
                     echo form_hidden('project_status_'.$status['id'],$value);
                    ?>
                   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 border-right">
                    <?php $where = ($_where == '' ? '' : $_where.' AND ').'status = '.$status['id']; ?>
                    <a href="#" onclick="dt_custom_view('project_status_<?php echo $status['id']; ?>','.table-projects','project_status_<?php echo $status['id']; ?>',true); return false;">
                     <h3 class="bold"><?php echo total_rows(db_prefix().'projects',$where); ?></h3>
                     <span style="color:<?php echo $status['color']; ?> project-status-<?php echo $status['id']; ?>">
                     <?php echo $status['name']; ?>
                     </span>
                   </a>
                 </div>
                 <?php } ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>

              <!-- ======================= Filter Section ==================== -->
               <hr class="hr-panel-heading" />
               <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(),array('method'=>'GET')); ?>
               <?php echo form_hidden('filter','true'); ?>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="select-placeholder">
                        <select name="range" id="range" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                           <option value="this_month" <?php if(!$this->input->get('range') || $this->input->get('range') == 'this_month'){echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo _l('staff_stats_this_month_total_logged_time'); ?></option>
                           <option value="last_month" <?php if($this->input->get('range') == 'last_month'){echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo _l('staff_stats_last_month_total_logged_time'); ?></option>
                           <option value="this_week" <?php if($this->input->get('range') == 'this_week'){echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo _l('staff_stats_this_week_total_logged_time'); ?></option>
                           <option value="last_week" <?php if($this->input->get('range') == 'last_week'){echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo _l('staff_stats_last_week_total_logged_time'); ?></option>
                           <option value="period" <?php if($this->input->get('range') == 'period'){echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo _l('period_datepicker'); ?></option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row mtop15">
                        <div class="col-md-12 period <?php if($this->input->get('range') != 'period'){echo 'hide';} ?>">
                           <?php echo render_date_input('period-from','',$this->input->get('period-from')); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 period <?php if($this->input->get('range') != 'period'){echo 'hide';} ?>">
                           <?php echo render_date_input('period-to','',$this->input->get('period-to')); ?>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success apply-timesheets-filters"><?php echo _l('apply'); ?></button> 
                     <br> <br> 
                     <p><a class="currentdaybtn" href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/tapetreports?filter=true&range=period&period-from=<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>&period-to=<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">Today</a></p> <style>
                     a.currentdaybtn {
    border: 1px solid #2597b3;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #55c0da;
    color: #fff;
    border-width: 0 1px 4px 1px;
}
 a.currentdaybtn:hover {
    background: #84c529;
    border-color: #3c763d;
}
</style>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <?php echo form_close(); ?>
               <!-- ======================= Filter Section ==================== -->

              <hr class="hr-panel-heading" />
             <?php echo form_hidden('custom_view'); ?>
             <?php $this->load->view('admin/tasks/reports/tapet_report_table_html'); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php init_tail(); ?>
<script>
$(function(){
     var ProjectsServerParams = {};

    ProjectsServerParams['range'] = '[name="range"]';
    ProjectsServerParams['period-from'] = '[name="period-from"]';
    ProjectsServerParams['period-to'] = '[name="period-to"]';

     $.each($('._hidden_inputs._filters input'),function(){
         ProjectsServerParams[$(this).attr('name')] = '[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]';
     });

     _table_api = initDataTable('.table-projects', admin_url+'tasks/tapet_report_table', undefined, undefined, ProjectsServerParams, <?php echo hooks()->apply_filters('projects_table_default_order', json_encode(array(0,'asc'))); ?>);

     if (_table_api) {
          _table_api.column(7).visible(false, false).columns.adjust();
      }
});

function CalculateTaskReportTableSummary(table){

  var intVal = function (i) {
      return typeof i === 'string' ?
              i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
              typeof i === 'number' ?
                  i : 0;
  };

  var api = table.api();

  var EstimatedTimeTotal = api
        .column( 3 )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );

  var RealTimeTotal = api
        .column( 5 )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );

  var EstimatedCostTotal = api
        .column( 6 )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );

  var RealCostTotal = api
        .column( 7 )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );
       
  var TotalPrice = api
        .column( 9 )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );     // facut de mine
        
        var PriceMinusRC = api
        .column( 10 )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );     // facut de mine

  var tblhtml = '';
  tblhtml += '<tr class="lastrowbold" id="anchor">';
  tblhtml += '<td></td>';
  tblhtml += '<td></td>';
  tblhtml += '<td></td>';
  tblhtml += '<td></td>';
  tblhtml += '<td></td>';
//   tblhtml += '<td> Total By Estimated Time: '+EstimatedTimeTotal.toFixed(2)+' Min</td>';
  tblhtml += '<td> Total By Real Time: '+RealTimeTotal.toFixed(2)+' Min </td>';
  tblhtml += '<td> Total By Estimated Cost: '+EstimatedCostTotal.toFixed(2)+' Lei</td>';
  tblhtml += '<td> Total By Real Cost: '+RealCostTotal.toFixed(2)+' Lei</td>';
  tblhtml += '<td id="alltaskspricetotal"> Total By Price: '+TotalPrice.toFixed(2)+' Lei</td>';     // facut de mine
  tblhtml += '<td> Price - Total Cost: '+ PriceMinusRC.toFixed(2)+' Lei</td>';
  tblhtml += '</tr>';     // facut de mine

  $(".table-projects tbody").append(tblhtml);
  //$(api.column(4).footer()).html('Total By Estimated Time'+EstimatedTimeTotal);
}

// window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// var header = document.getElementById("#DataTables_Table_0");
// var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// function myFunction() {
//   if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
//     header.classList.add("sticky");
//   } else {
//     header.classList.remove("sticky");
//   }
// }
 $(function() {
    var aboveHeight = $("#aboveFrame").outerHeight(true);
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#frame').height( $(window).height() - aboveHeight );
    }).resize();
});

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")].forEach(
    row => row.classList.toggle("hide",row.cells[1].textContent.trim()==="0")
  );
});

   
</script>
<style type="text/css">
th.sorting_asc {
  display: none;
}

td.sorting_1 {
  display: none;
}
.hide { display: none }


  #anchor {
    position: fixed;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 41%;
}
  tr.lastrowbold {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
/*#DataTables_Table_0 thead {*/
/*position: sticky;*/
/*  top: 0;*/
/*  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
/*}*/
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important; 
}

</style>
</body>
</html>
<script> <script> window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")].forEach(
    row => row.classList.toggle("hide",row.cells[1].textContent.trim()==="0")
  );
}); </script></script>
````

Comment: do you use php to output the table rows? if so why not just do an if statement to check if the value is 0, if it isn't, then output the row?

Comment: hi, yes i use php to output, but i am beginner and i don;t know how to do that if statement :( can you give me an example pls

Comment: if you show your php loop instead of the rendered html that would be helpful

Comment: i posted the php as a comment on this post

Comment: The php you posted does not create a table

Comment: We need to see the code that processes `$row[]`

Comment: i posted all the files that i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your PHP, I would consider

```
if ($outputStatus > 0) {
  $row[] = $outputStatus;
  $row[] = $outputName;
  $row[] = $itemName;
  $row[] = "<span style='font-weight:900'>$duration</span> | ($durationNatural $durationRest)";  // facut de mine
  $row[] = round($realTime/60);
  $row[] = round($estimateCost);
  $row[] = round($realCost);
  $row[] = round($realCost);
  $row[] = $calC;   // facut de mine
  $row[] = $calCminusrealcost;   // facut de mine
  $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}
```

---

Otherwise use JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")].forEach(
    row => row.classList.toggle("hide",row.cells[1].textContent.trim()==="0")
  );
});
```

```css
th.sorting_asc {
  display: none;
}

td.sorting_1 {
  display: none;
}
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<table class="table table-projects dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="DataTables_Table_0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorting_asc" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0" style="">#</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Task Status</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Task Name</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Items</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Estimated Time (min.)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Real Time (min.)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Estimated Cost (Lei)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">Real Cost (Lei)</th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0"><span class="mrp">Manual Real Price (Lei Fara TVA)&nbsp;</span> <span class="prc">Price</span></th>
      <th class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" tabindex="0">
        <div class="priority1">Priority</div><span class="ceva">Price</span> <span class="priceminus">Price - Real Cost</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1886">1886</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1887">1887</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1889">1889</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1890">1890</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1927">1927</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1928">1928</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1959">1959</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1960">1960</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">0</span> | (0 0)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0"><a href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1969">1969</a></td>
      <td><span class="inline-block label" style="color:#84c529;border:1px solid #84c529;">Expediat Tapet <img src="http://crm.amco.ro/wallpaper.png" alt="Girl in a jacket">
                    <div class="dropdown inline-block mleft5 table-export-exclude"><a class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="tableTaskStatus-1969" style="font-size:14px;vertical-align:middle;"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change Status"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><br></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td><a class="display-block main-tasks-table-href-name" href="https://crm.amco.ro/admin/tasks/view/1969">test 4.02.21</a></td>
      <td>
        <div>1.Manopera <strong>(1)</strong></div>
      </td>
      <td><span style="font-weight:900;">60</span> | (1 0)</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>83</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>101.26</td>
      <td>94.52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lastrowbold" id="anchor">
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td>Total By Real Time: 4.00 Min</td>
      <td>Total By Estimated Cost: 83.00 Lei</td>
      <td>Total By Real Cost: 7.00 Lei</td>
      <td id="alltaskspricetotal">Total By Price: 101.26 Lei</td>
      <td>Price - Total Cost: 94.52 Lei</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What does `still dont work` mean? Errors what?

Comment: It obviously works here using YOUR HTML, so what do you mean

Comment: the rows are still visible

Comment: If you run the snippet I posted, they all hide. So what is missing from your HTML?

Comment: Yes i saw that, but when i put in my page it doesnt work maybe because i use php to output the row

Comment: If the php generates the table you posted, my code should work if you place it correctly inside script tags. I updated the code to run after the page loaded